# how check password reset token if it has expired or not in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to reset the password by using token, the token send by email ,if the token is true go to the change password page , how could I do that ?
my controller:

```
 function validateReminderToken($token)
{
    $token = DB::table('password_resets')
        ->where('token','=',$token)
        ->where('created_at','>',Carbon::now()->subHours(2))
        ->first();
    return view('Admin/Page/Email/resetPassword'.compact('token'));

}
```

this is my view :

```
<h1>this is test</h1>
<a href="{{$token}}">click</a>
```

this is my rout:

```
        Route::get('/validate/{token}','resetPasswordController@validateReminderToken')->name('validate');
```

Comment: Are you using Laravels auth package?  If you do, the functionality is already present.

Comment: no I am not using laravel auth package,  am using mailtrap and when I am click on this open mailtrap page

Comment: `return view('Admin/Page/Email/resetPassword'.compact('token'));` I think the dot `.` before `compact` should be a comma `,`

Comment: I am using with ,but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

So the general way of doing this is:

1. On click of `reset` Button create a new entry in the `password_rests` table.
2. Send the `Email` to the user with a action button containing the `reset URL`.
3. If the user clicks this button, `redirect` him/her to the `reset page`, but only if the token is still valid (you can check the created_at of the password_resets entry where the token matches).
4. Let the user `reset` his/her password or give an `error` that the token is not working anymore.

---

**@edit1**

You will need a setup like following, so that your mail will work correctly:

1. Create a route which sends you to the reset page: (e.g. the one you already have `validate`
2. In your mail you will need to set the link of the button to the desired page:`href="{{route('validate', $token)}}"`
3. If the user clicks the button your `validateReminderToken()` method will be called.
4. Make sure that you dont override the sent token with the entry you are getting out of the database

Comment: the email go to the inbox in mailtrap , when I am click on click button it goes to the mailtrap page

Comment: @melissa i added some explanation

Comment: @ Aless55  I try this but it does not go to this rout????

Comment: @melissa where does it go then?